# Disabling RC4 ciphering in Apache 2.4 vhost and still available

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, openssl, letsencrypt

In Apache 2.4, my vhost include the following :

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qualification.teamagora.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/qualification.teamagora.com/privkey.pem
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
```

which should deactivates RC4 ciphering...

Neverthelless, SSLLabs shows that the following ciphering is available !

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)           INSECURE   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)           INSECURE   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)  INSECURE   128
```

Where can I deactivate RC4 completely ?

Why is the vhost configuration file not taken into account (I did service apache2 restart)

Comment: It's not nice to start a bounty and then abandon it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `SSLCipherSuite` does not disable RC4. It should look more like :

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

You should follow
[Recommended configurations](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations)
from Mozilla, since a secure TLS configuration is more than disabling RC4.
You will find in the article a link to the
[Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/)
that makes it easy to configure proper cipher suites per server and browser
types.